# Hiding an image on mobile only using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to have my site remove an image only on mobile which I was able to accomplish using

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .slide-6996 {
    display:block !important;
  }
  .slide-6996 {
    display:none !important;
  }
}
```

However, I also would still like to display the text that was on the slide that I am now not showing. I have tried this in CSS, but it obviously didn't work.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .slide-6996 {
    display:block !important;
  }

  .slide-6996 {
    display:none !important;
    #slide-content {
      display: block !important; 
    }
  }
}
```

My HTML for this specific instance is

```
<div id="slide-6996" class="slide slide-6996 cycle-slide-active slide-left light" style="background-image:url(http://18.205.33.160/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ITData-Home-Page2018-01-edited.jpg);">    
  <div class="slide-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slide-caption">
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h1><strong>COMPREHENSIVE IT SERVICES YOU CAN TRUST</strong></h1>
        </div>

        <h2 class="slide-title"> Let us help you develop an IT Optimization Strategy and Define your technological priorities </h2>

        <a class="slide-link button button-medium" href="http://18.205.33.160/index.php/itone-method/?customize_changeset_uuid=56ed31cf-ab75-46c7-bf6a-d1eb013fed32&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on" target="_self"> Learn how we can help you succeed </a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should also be worth noting that I am on WordPress and am open-minded to any suggested plugins that may fix my issue.

Comment: I do not see any image in html except `<div class="slide-image">` which is also not closed. Are you missing something?

Comment: where is .slide-6996 in your html ? also no image seen

Comment: Please remove !important, because it cannot be overridden by the css. Add display: block for the text and display:none for the image inside the media query.

Comment: Are you using SCSS or plain CSS?

Comment: i dont know how to edit my post, but I accidentally left out <div id="slide-6996" class="slide slide-6996 cycle-slide-active slide-left light" style="background-image:url(http://18.205.33.160/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ITData-Home-Page2018-01-edited.jpg);"> on the top of my html, should i delete and repost?

Comment: Click the button at the bottom that says edit

Comment: @3ocene I did that earlier and got confused when I saw someone else already edited, it is now updated. TIL I am stupid haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override inline CSS using external CSS, but what you can do is edit your HTML a bit. By adding a new class in that div and in the external CSS you can make rules for what and when to apply.

So, in first line add a new class "background-cls"—your first line needs to be like this:

```
<div id="slide-6996" class="slide slide-6996 cycle-slide-active slide-left light background-cls">
```

Then in your external CSS add something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .background-cls {
    background-image: none !important;
  }
}
.background-cls {
  background-image: url(http://18.205.33.160/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ITData-Home-Page2018-01-edited.jpg);
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2xb34dev/

Comment: unfortunately this did not work, it projected on desktop how i wanted it but the background image is still there on mobile, I think this is putting me on the right track though of what I need to do :)

Comment: this actually does the exact opposite of what I want now hahaha, it projects no background image on desktop and does on mobile, definitely on the right track :)

Comment: This is working on fiddle (try to resize on that vertical divider), so it should work on mobile too.
Maybe it's just about the screen size - try to experiment with @media max-width size.
Also if this answer brings you closer to solution - feel free fo accept my answer.

Comment: Sorry, you are actually correct I was making a very noob mistake of just editing the HTML in my browser (and doing CSS on the actual source code) I will put the new HTML in and report back, thank you for the help :)

Comment: I can't figure out how to change my html in wordpress with this theme, but I am going to go ahead and mark this correct since this seems to be the right solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media` and then hide that class.

```
@media (max-width: 576px){
  .yourclass{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

You can choose 767px or 992px for larger size or you can give your `@media` with between sizee like following example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) and (min-width: 767px) {
  .yourclass {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: didnt work for me, but thanks for taking the time to try and help

Comment: @jblaupunkt use edited question and report back please

Answer (score 0):

With your markup this should work:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .slide-6996 .slide-image {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Hope that solves it.

Comment: this brought back the picture I am trying to get rid of and the text, but thank you for trying to help

Comment: I guess i misread - do you want to hide just .slide-image under 480px?

Comment: yes, and still keep the text and button if possible

Comment: Have you try with: display:none!important as i suggest?